# How to set default class to first element of *ngFor in angular

Tags: angular

```
<ul class="nav flex-column">


  <ng-container *ngFor="let cat of Category"  >
    <span>{{change}}</span>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link "  [class.bg]="temp===cat" (click)="clicked(cat)" href="#">{{cat}}</a>  
    </li>
  </ng-container>

</ul>
```

I have a sidebar and I want by default to show the first li anchor tag with active class and after that when I click other li I need to change .
I have implemented the later part but how to set the default class

**EDIT:-**

```
   <li class="nav-item"  [class.bg]="change === true && i==0 ">
        <a class="nav-link "  [class.bg]="temp===cat" (click)="clicked(cat)" href="#">{{cat}}</a>  
    </li>
```

I used variable called change  to check if the menu is not clicked and index variable i as suggested by `Penggy` to determine the first menu item and the code works

But I found out another thing and if somebody can help me understand it would be great

```
<a class="nav-link "  [class.bg]="temp===cat" [class.bg]="change === true && i==0 " (click)="clicked(cat)" href="#">{{cat}}</a>
```

the above code works but it stops working if you change the order of [class.bg ] statements
{{cat}} 
The above code does not work why is this

Comment: [ngClass] = "{'white': (temp==cat)}"

Comment: @SharmaVikram that part is working fine [class.bg]="temp===cat" is used to set the back ground for currently clicked menu item and it works fine but I want to  set default selected item on load

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NgFor` exports `index` variable which means for the index of the current element in array, see **[doc](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables)**. You just need to declare it in `ngFor` expression in order to use it.

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let cat of Category; let i = index;"  >
   <span>{{change}}</span>
   <li class="nav-item" [ngClass]="{'active-class': i === 0}">
     <a class="nav-link "  [class.bg]="temp===cat" (click)="clicked(cat)" href="#">{{cat}}</a>  
   </li>
 </ng-container>
```

You can also use `first` variable exported by `ngFor`.

```
 <ng-container *ngFor="let cat of Category; let f = first;"  >
   <span>{{change}}</span>
   <li class="nav-item" [ngClass]="{'active-class': f}">
     <a class="nav-link "  [class.bg]="temp===cat" (click)="clicked(cat)" href="#">{{cat}}</a>  
   </li>
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: Penggy thanks for the roper answer can you please check the edit and clarify my doubt accepted your answer

Comment: Angular exposes a local variable `first`. Maybe using it will be more descriptive? Local variables reference https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables

Comment: @SachinDivakar Those two `[class.bg]` will conflict with each other. Better to merge them together.

Comment: can you please show how to merge them together as well in your answer

Comment: @SachinDivakar try with `[class.bg]="temp===cat || (change === true && i==0) "`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
<li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link "  [ngClass]='{"bg": temp===cat}' (click)="clicked(cat)" href="#">{{cat}}</a>  
    </li>
```